# How can I set up a WiFi-hotspot to host files which can be downloaded by an other device later

Tags: wireless-networking, file-sharing, hotspot

There is an app on the Play Store named Super Beam and what it does is it sends file by starting a WiFi-hotspot gives its name and its password, and an IP address to connect to from an other device.
And if I connect there and type the IP I get a webpage with a option to download the files I wanted to send.
I would like to set this up manually (preferably on Linux).

But, how?

Comment: Not a hotspot but an *ad hoc* connection. Please [edit] and describe what do you want to do. As it is your question is unclear.

Comment: @Michael Sounds like Pig wants to host an ad hoc network from a Linux PC, with file sharing enabled, and a simple way of directing a client to a shared file

Comment: Re-reading and re-thinking about it, it seems the OP refers to a simple Samba share app for Android and muddies the waters by mentioning "hotspot". I was initially confused because there are also file sharing apps via a direct connection (*ad hoc*). So, clarification is in order. Making a network share in Windows or Linux is trivial when using a common protocol. Anything else is tricky and might not work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I would like to set this up manually (preferably on Linux).

If you are asking to get this thing done on a Linux machine, then maybe you can use `Python` for this.

Python is pre-installed in almost every UNIX or GNU/Linux distributions, packs many feature reach modules inside it, one of which is **`SimpleHTTPServer`** Module. This module lets you create a webserver that is commonly `used by programmers for testing purposes`. It can be simply used for file-sharing that is what you want.

#### First, get to know what `version of Python` is installed on your machine.

```
$ python -v
```

OR

```
$ python --version
```

If Python is installed on your machine, It will probably show you either `2.7.x` or `3.x`. However, If not installed will give an error and prompt for installation. [Install the latest version](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install3/linux/).

#### Creating the Web Server

- **On `Python 2.7.x`**

  ```
  $ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8989
  ```
- **On `Python 3.x`**

  ```
  $ python -m http.server 8989
  ```

In both cases, it will start a python web server for your `current directory`, on port 8989 (By default 8000). `Note down this port.`

`NOTE` :

1. If there is a index.html file at that directory, it will be served by default, else contents of that directory will be served.
2. You can use any port but to use any port below 1024 (Because they are reserved ports), you will need to be Root. For that use `sudo`.

#### Accessing the Files and directories (or the Webpage)

- **`On the Same Device`**

  Open up your favorite web browser, type **`127.0.0.1:8000`** in the URL bar and hit enter.
- **`On another device`**

  Find your System's IP address (on which Python web server is created)

  ```
  $ ip addr show | grep inet

  OR

  $ ifconfig | grep "inet addr"
  ```

  `Note down this ip address`.

  Now, On another device, open your browser and in the URL bar write

  ```
  IP Address : port
  ```

  You are good to go. Now you can access whatever files and directories are present in the current directory (inside which you created the server).

#### A Good Practice

Create a `webserver` directory and put whatever files you want to serve as or share to others in this directory, and then create python web server in this directory.

This way No One will be able to see the rest of files on your system using URL manipulation.

[See this](https://www.pcsuggest.com/best-lightweight-web-server-linux/) for other alternatives.